# SYS.DBMS_DDL.WRAP not allowing pragma and intctx

Tags: plsql

I am using the below procedure to wrap the PL/SQL Code.

```
declare
  l_source  DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
  l_wrap    DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
  l_wrap1    clob;
  typ_ibt   utl_file.file_type;
  cnt       number := 0;
  v_directory varchar2(400) := 'd:\ftpedi\eqpm\eqpm_hold\';

  cursor cur_name_get is
  select distinct name object_name,type object_type
  from   user_source
  where  type = 'PROCEDURE'
  and    name = 'PROCESS_TIME_INSERT';

  cursor cut_text_get ( p_type in varchar2 , p_name in varchar2 )  is
  select replace(text,chr(10),'') text
  from   user_source
  where  type = p_type
  and    name = p_name;
begin

for i in cur_name_get
loop
     l_source.delete;l_wrap.delete;
     open cut_text_get ( i.object_type,i.object_name );
     fetch cut_text_get bulk collect into l_source;
     close  cut_text_get;
     l_source (1) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE ' || l_source (1);
     l_wrap := SYS.DBMS_DDL.WRAP(ddl => l_source,
                                lb  => 1,
                                ub  => l_source.count);
     for i in 1..l_wrap.count
     loop
        if i = 1
        then
            l_wrap1 := l_wrap(i);
        else
            l_wrap1 := l_wrap1 || l_wrap(i);
        end if;
        insert into ibt_global_inter_transfer ( git_process_id,git_c_1)
        values ( 3004, l_wrap1 );
     end loop;                                
  end loop;  

exception when others
then
    dbms_output.put_line('sqlerrm '||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;
```

The above procedures warps the normal procedure, but not allowing the special character like 'PRAGMA'.

The below is the sample procedure, which is not wrapping.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE xml_insert ( p_in_xml in xmltype ,p_status out varchar2,p_message out varchar2) is
intctx DBMS_XMLSTORE.ctxtype;
rows number;
begin
    p_status := 'S';
    p_message := 'Success';

    intctx := Dbms_xmlstore.newcontext('IBT_GLOBAL_INTER_TRANSFER');
    dbms_xmlstore.clearupdatecolumnlist(intctx);
    dbms_xmlstore.setupdatecolumn(intCtx,'GIT_PROCESS_ID');
    dbms_xmlstore.setupdatecolumn(intCtx,'GIT_SESSION_ID');
    rows := Dbms_xmlstore.insertxml(intctx,p_in_xml);
    dbms_xmlstore.closecontext(intctx);
exception when others
then
    p_status := 'R';
    p_message := sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
    return;    
end;
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: It works for me on 12.1.0.1.0.  However, I had to make a few minor modifications to run your code, such as changing `name = 'PROCESS_TIME_INSERT';`, adding a `pragma`, and replacing the insert with a dbms_output.  If this is a parsing bug those minor changes could make a big difference.  Could you slightly modify your code so others can test a 100% identical version?

Comment: Hi @jonearles, Can you post the modified code as a solution so that I can see the changes you were done in above snippet.

Comment: @Sravan: I added the code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

(I misunderstood the problem.  I thought you meant the wrapped code wasn't created, now I understand the real problem is that the wrapped output does not compile.)

Remove the `replace`, there needs to be white space between some of the lines.

Replace:

```
  --select replace(text,chr(10),'') text
```

with:

```
  select text
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE xml_insert ( p_in_xml in xmltype ,p_status out varchar2,p_message out varchar2) is
intctx DBMS_XMLSTORE.ctxtype;
rows number;
pragma autonomous_transaction; --ADDED
begin
    p_status := 'S';
    p_message := 'Success';

    intctx := Dbms_xmlstore.newcontext('IBT_GLOBAL_INTER_TRANSFER');
    dbms_xmlstore.clearupdatecolumnlist(intctx);
    dbms_xmlstore.setupdatecolumn(intCtx,'GIT_PROCESS_ID');
    dbms_xmlstore.setupdatecolumn(intCtx,'GIT_SESSION_ID');
    rows := Dbms_xmlstore.insertxml(intctx,p_in_xml);
    dbms_xmlstore.closecontext(intctx);
exception when others
then
    p_status := 'R';
    p_message := sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
    return;    
end;
/
```

PL/SQL Block wrapping code:

```
declare
  l_source  DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
  l_wrap    DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
  l_wrap1    clob;
  typ_ibt   utl_file.file_type;
  cnt       number := 0;
  v_directory varchar2(400) := 'd:\ftpedi\eqpm\eqpm_hold\';

  cursor cur_name_get is
  select distinct name object_name,type object_type
  from   user_source
  where  type = 'PROCEDURE'
  and    name = 'XML_INSERT'; --CHANGED

  cursor cut_text_get ( p_type in varchar2 , p_name in varchar2 )  is
  --select replace(text,chr(10),'') text  --WOOPS!
  select text
  from   user_source
  where  type = p_type
  and    name = p_name;
begin

for i in cur_name_get
loop
     l_source.delete;l_wrap.delete;
     open cut_text_get ( i.object_type,i.object_name );
     fetch cut_text_get bulk collect into l_source;
     close  cut_text_get;
     l_source (1) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE ' || l_source (1);
     l_wrap := SYS.DBMS_DDL.WRAP(ddl => l_source,
                                lb  => 1,
                                ub  => l_source.count);
     for i in 1..l_wrap.count
     loop
        if i = 1
        then
            l_wrap1 := l_wrap(i);
        else
            l_wrap1 := l_wrap1 || l_wrap(i);
        end if;
        --insert into ibt_global_inter_transfer ( git_process_id,git_c_1)
        --values ( 3004, l_wrap1 );
        dbms_output.put_line(l_wrap1);
     end loop;                                
  end loop;  

exception when others
then
    dbms_output.put_line('sqlerrm '||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;
/
```

Comment: @jonearls Thanks for your code. Unfortunately we have only Oracle11g. We will try it in Oracle11g and let you know the status.

Comment: Hi @jonearles while compile the wrapped source its give the below error

Comment: Processing ... 
(1):PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ISINTCTX" when expecting one of the following:
(1):
(1):   ; is with authid as cluster order using external
(1):   deterministic parallel_enable pipelined result_cache
(1):The symbol "is" was substituted for "ISINTCTX" to continue.
(2):PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
(2):
(2):   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
(2):   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
(2):   exists prior

Procedure XML_INSERT compiled with errors; status INVALID

Comment: We are facing the same issue in Oracle 11g

Comment: @Sravan See the update, I think the issue was removing too much whitespace caused some of the tokens to merge.